# Why can I sign and verify JWT's with a RSA-algorithm using EC-key-pairs?

Tags: node.js, jwt, cryptography, rsa, ecdsa

I use the crypto core-module in node.js to generate an EC-key-pair.

I then use this key-pair to sign and verify JWT's.

I would expect the signing/verification to only work when using an EC-algorithm.

However it seems to be working with any algorithm except HMAC.

From my understanding, this shouldn't be possible.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you for reading my question.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'secp256k1',
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem'
  }
})

const token = jwt.sign({}, keyPair.privateKey, {
  algorithm: 'ES256' // I expect this to work, but it seems to be also working with e.g. "RS256" or "PS512", which I don't understand.
})

const verify = jwt.verify(token, keyPair.publicKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

This made me curious too, so I tried to dig up sources.
If you follow what happens during signing a jwt, you will eventually get to [this](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwa/blob/master/index.js#L149):

```
function createKeySigner(bits) {
 return function sign(thing, privateKey) {
    checkIsPrivateKey(privateKey);
    thing = normalizeInput(thing);
    // Even though we are specifying "RSA" here, this works with ECDSA
    // keys as well.
    var signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA' + bits);
    var sig = (signer.update(thing), signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64'));
    return fromBase64(sig);
  }
}
```

This doesn't answer why though. So digging deeper, `crypto` is implemented in C, and I think [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto_keys.cc#L733) is the relevant part. If I understand correctly, the reason it works mostly comes down to the fact that it is just read as a string/buffer.